# How given script makes executables in /usr/local/bin/

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

While doing project , I found a script that is  bounced over my head. Can you help me to understand this script . Please explain this script step by step.

**SCRIPT**

```
if ! [ -f /usr/local/bin/XXX -a -f /usr/local/bin/YYY -a -f /usr/local/bin/ZZZ ]
then
    if [ "`uname`" = "Linux" ]
    then
        UUDECODE="uudecode -o /dev/stdout"
    else
        UUDECODE="uudecode -p"
    fi
    cat $0 | awk 'printme == "1" {print} /^DATA BEGINS HERE/ {printme = "1"}' | ${UUDECODE} | (cd /usr/local/bin ; sudo tar xzf - --unlink)
    sudo chmod AAAA /usr/local/bin/XXX /usr/local/bin/YYY
fi
```

**My understanding so far**

1. This script checks if XXX , YYY , ZZZ is present in /usr/local/bin , is present or not.
2. If not then it enters in the body of if.
3. If current OS is Linux, then it do
4. But after that I didn't understand.

Strange after running this script these three executables are in /usr/local/bin. 
Explain below script line by line please.

**One thing that I mention that, at the end of script, there is some unreadable data is there, starting from "DATA BEGINS HERE". Is this script copies this data to /usr/local/bin ?**

Answer (score 4):

If it is Linux, it sets UUDECODE to one form of calling the command `uudecode`, if not, another one. It isn't standard, so how to call it varies. Not very smart, if you ask me.

The line starting `cat $0` does the real work. `$0` is the name of the running process, i.e., of the current script. Again, will mostly work but can be fooled.

The contents of the script are piped to the `awk` script, which copies all the text after `DATA BEGINS HERE` to its output, which is piped to `uudecode` (the command set up before). `uudecode` takes text and makes a binary of it (the pair `uuencode`/`uudecode` where used to ship binaries around as text before HTTP and others became popular), the result is piped to the command in '()', which first changes into `/usr/local/bin` and then unpacks the input with `tar` there. The `--unlink` first deletes any existing file.

Where does this come from?!

Comment: This is related to my college project.